# Cell decomposition in higher dimensions (sphere&projective space)

Tags: algebraic-topology

I don't understand how one constructs a cell decomposition for the sphere or the projective space, when we are more than 3-dimensional. My problem is how can I make a cell composition of the 3-sphere without being able to visialize the 3-sphere?

Comment: Can you prove that $\mathbb B^n / \partial \mathbb B^n \cong \mathbb S^n$ ?  Do you see why this answer to your question ?

Comment: Yes, $\mathbb{B} \cong \mathbb{S}^{n}_{+} $ . If you then glue together the equator by continuous deformations one gets $\mathbb{S}^n$. But I don't see how this is an answert to my question. I mean there are also compositions as $2 e_0 , \ldots , 2 e_n$ , which I cannot visualize that way.

Comment: Ok so what is the problem ? The sphere $\mathbb S^n$ decompose as a n cell (the interior of the disk) and a 0-cell (the image of the equator by the quotient map).

Comment: One constructs cell decompositions the way many unvisualizable objects are constructed: by generalization, analogy, and guesswork. First do $S^1$, and then do $S^2$, each of which you can visualize. Look for a common pattern for the descriptions of the cells and their characteristic maps. Then see how to apply that pattern to $S^3,S^4,...$, which leads to guesses for their cells and characteristic maps. Prove that your guess works, that the definition of a cell complex is satisfied.